# C++ ofstream : Always write onthe 1st line

Tags: c++, io, overwrite

I would like to know how could I write always to the first line of a file.
I have numbers to share via a text file to another soft, and I want to write those numbers periodically on the first line.

Thanks.

eo

Comment: maybe i'm wrong, but `seekp`-method set a put-pointer.

Comment: do you want to replace the first line or to insert a new line as first ?

Comment: @dwalter I want to replace the line

Comment: just set put-pointer to zero-position with `seekp`-method.

Comment: if possible use another approach for your inter-process communication ((named) pipes, shared memory, sockets, whatever).

Comment: Assuming your first line can grow and shrink, that's indeed a bad idea. A pipe would be easier (on 1 computer) or network sockets (Qt offers client/server classes ready for use...)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to completely rewrite the file, discarding it's contents then simply use `trunc` mode. However, if there is any other content that you want to preserve then the easiest way would be to read the file into memory, change the first line and write everything back. I think it wouldn't be possible to change the first line directly unless you are overwriting the same amount of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this two functions:

ostream& seekp ( streampos pos );
ostream& seekp ( streamoff off, ios_bas:seekdir dir );

Answer (score 0):

maybe this solves your problem

```
 ofstream out("foo.txt");
 out << "foo";
 out << "\r" << "bar";
```

this will leave a file with only bar in it.

2nd method: 
if the file only contains one line you could open it with `ofstream::trunc` and close it after each write

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not massive then you could write a new new file copying across each line except for the custom first line. Then afterwards replace the original.

```
void ReplaceFirstLine(string filename)
{
ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;
infile.open(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in);
outfile.open("tempname.txt", ios_base::out);

bool first = true;
string s;
while (getline(infile, s, '\n'))
    {
    if (first)
        outfile << "my new first line\n";
    else
        outfile << s << endl;
    first = false;
    }

infile.close();
outfile.close();
::CopyFileA("tempname.txt", filename.c_str(), FALSE); // or Linux equivalent
}
```